# readpst error "could not get root record"

Tags: mbox

I have installed readpst package and while converting pst file to mbox using "readpst -r outlook.pst".I get following error message:

Could not get root record

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using the -S switch. I compacted the PST and then it seemed to work.
According to the source code comment the problem is "first record is main record":

```
d_ptr = pstfile.d_head; // first record is main record
item  = pst_parse_item(&pstfile, d_ptr, NULL);
if (!item || !item->message_store) {
    DEBUG_RET();
    DIE(("Could not get root record\n"));
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.